# Relation to few tables by pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Users can attach files to the post: images or videos.

The structure of the database is as follows:

```
posts
   id
images
   id
videos
   id
post_attachment
   post_id
   attachment_id (id from images or videos table)
   attachment_type ('image' or 'video')
```

The difficulty is that, depending on the type of attachment, we should **refer to different tables**.

What relation of laravel functions should I apply to the `Post` model to get all the attachments through the `post_attachment` table?

I think this relationship is from a series of morph, but I can not understand exactly which one.

```
class Post {
     public function attachments () {
        return $this->morph?????
     }
}
```

Help me please to write correct relation for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need a pivot table at all, you can just create relationships between `Attachment`and `Video` using `hasMany()`, for example. Alternatively, to simplify your database structure, I would organize everything under a `PostAttachment` model

An example would be:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function attachment(){
        return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class);
    }
}
```

and your Attachment model:

```
class Attachment extends Model
{
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

and perhaps on your table, have a field which specifies the different types of attachments allowed:

`$table->enum('attachment_type', ['video', 'image']);`